# How to pass data to Spring controller method, when user click on <a> anchor tag html

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

In the following code when user clicks on New Messages link in Home screen i need to send input field value to controller. I can't send the data as part of URL.Is there any other way of achieving this.

```
    homepage.html

    <input type="hidden" value="newMessages" /> 
    <a href="@{/msgSearch}" >New Messages </a>


    @Controller
    public class HomeController{
       @RequestMapping("/msgSearch")
       public String messageSearch(Model model, HttpSession session){

            return "msgCenter";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes u can use ajax for sending data  to the back -end.

Comment: You need to write the javascript or jquery for that.

Comment: Rather it should be <a href="/msgSearch/value" >New Messages </a>

Comment: @DipakThoke How can we achieve this using ajax call? Browser URL itself will change, here it will redirect to Message Center

Comment: @TechBreak The problem here is User can also directly navigate to Message center ,by clicking on Message center. I cant modify the URL.

Comment: @ak38 yes we can achive it after submitting data using ajax in the sucess of the ajax you can redirect that page.

Comment: @DipakThoke, I will be little clear with My requirement, here controller will return the Command Object 'SearchOptions.class' to 'msgCenter' view. My requirement is i have to set the status to 'NEW' if the request come from home page and return to view. In other cases it will be 'ALL'

Answer (score 0):

This might be a easier solution as you want to update your url as well.

Use this HTML, here a button is used instead of link.

```
<form action="@{/msgSearch}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="newMessages" value="newMessages" />
    <button type="submit" value="New Messages">New Messages</button>
</form>
```

Make the button look like link (if you have to) using the following css.

```
button {
     background:none!important;
     border:none; 
     padding:0!important;
     font: inherit;
     /*border is optional*/
     border-bottom:1px solid #444; 
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

And your controller might look like the following or something else based on your project or requirement

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{
    @RequestMapping("/msgSearch")
    public String messageSearch(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
        String msgParam = request.getParameter("newMessage");
        // use the msgParam
        return "msgCenter";
    }
}
```

Comment: 'msgSearch' is a view (here it is a thymeleaf template ') . I have to look whether this solution is feasible or not . please update your solution as your input field must have name attribute with value "newMessage" . Then only we can access this using request object

Comment: good catch, updated the answer. Try this and let me know, I believe it should work.